# How to pass data from JavaScript to JavaFX

Tags: java, javascript, javafx-8

In my JavaFX application, I have a WebView to load HTML contents. Is there a way to pass Javascript variables and manipulate it in JavaFX App. Let's say I have a variable `FULLNAME` in Javascript and I want to display it in a TextField in JavaFX. Is it possible? Can you give an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible - assuming your webview is in a `webView` variable, and you want your `FULLNAME` variable loaded into `fullNameField`, try executing this on the Java side:

```
String fullName = (String) webview1.getEngine().executeScript("FULLNAME;");
fullNameField.setText(fullName);
```

Comment: Wow! Just that simple?

Comment: Yep - check here for more: https://blogs.oracle.com/javafx/entry/communicating_between_javascript_and_javafx

Comment: The code should be run after the webengine is completed loading the html. Namely when the state is SUCCESSED.

Comment: @Evan Knowles, Sir, is it possible to add a changelistener so that if the javascript variable will change the javafx variable also changes. I mean if FULLNAME will change , the Javafx TextField will also change? Is it possible?

Comment: @EthylCasin I don't think you can add a `changeListener`, but you can call back into Java from JavaScript whenever you update `FULLNAME`. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/30390913/2137269

Comment: @UlukBiy: `State.SUCCEEDED`