# How to catch return value from javascript in javafx?

Tags: javascript, javafx, javafx-webengine

I am executing a javascript code in my webview of JavaFX application. I need to make it execute repeatedly whenever there is a mouse click and get the element details into a java variable. I'm using the below code and using Firebug Lite. In Firebug console, required items are printing. But I want it returned to java application.

```
engine.documentProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Document>() {
            @Override public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Document> prop, Document oldDoc, Document newDoc) {
                enableFirebug(engine);
                Object obj=engine.executeScript("var lastElement = null; "
                        + "document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {"
                        + "if (e.target != lastElement) {"
                        + "lastElement = e.target;"
                        + "console.log(lastElement.name);"
                        + "return lastElement.name;"
                        + "}}, false);");
                System.out.println(obj.toString());
            }
        });
```

It is getting executed when the page is loaded, but not after every mouse click. Please suggest me how to modify it.

Comment: You want whenever the user clicks on anything on the page?

Comment: yes @EvanKnowles, everytime user clicks on an element, I want to get the element ID/name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try calling this the other way around. Assuming you're loading your page as

```
final WebEngine webEngine = webview.getEngine();
webEngine.load("http://localhost/demo/clickHandler/");
```

We're going to set a listener for the successful state - basically we're going to inject a Java class into the JavaScript and have it call us back. Let's create a `WebController` that checks what is passed in and prints out the ID:

```
public class WebController {
    public void printId(Object object) {
        if (org.w3c.dom.html.HTMLElement.class.isAssignableFrom(object.getClass())) {
            org.w3c.dom.html.HTMLElement it = (org.w3c.dom.html.HTMLElement) object;
            System.out.println("Id is " + it.getId());
        }
    }
}
```

Now on successful load, we inject this into the app as `clickController`.

```
    webEngine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<State>() {
          @Override
          public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends State> ov, State oldState, State newState) {
              if (newState == State.SUCCEEDED) {
                  JSObject window = (JSObject) webEngine.executeScript("window");
                  window.setMember("clickController", new WebController());
              }
          }
      }
    );
```

Now we need some JavaScript on the page to call us back. Assuming you're using jQuery, add this code to your page:

```
$(function () {
    $('*').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        clickController.printId(this);
    });
});
```

Now when anything is clicked on, a call back will be made to `webController`, which will check that the object is an `HTMLElement` and print out its ID (or null if there is no ID).

Not using jQuery makes it a bit harder but you can add this to the end of your document:

```
var nonJQuery = function (event) {
    clickController.printId(this);
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
};
var elements = document.querySelectorAll("*");
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].addEventListener("click", nonJQuery, false);
}
```

If adding content to the document is not possible, you can execute the script to add the click handler in the succeeded function. Update the succeeded function to look as follows:

```
    webEngine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<State>() {
          @Override
          public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends State> ov, State oldState, State newState) {
              if (newState == State.SUCCEEDED) {
                  JSObject window = (JSObject) webEngine.executeScript("window");
                  webEngine.executeScript("var nonJQuery = function (event) {\n" +
                          "    clickController.printId(this);\n" +
                          "    event.preventDefault();\n" +
                          "    event.stopPropagation();\n" +
                          "};\n" +
                          "var elements = document.querySelectorAll(\"*\");\n" +
                          "for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {\n" +
                          "    elements[i].addEventListener(\"click\", nonJQuery, false);\n" +
                          "}");
                  window.setMember("clickController", new WebController());
              }
          }
      }
    );
```

Finally, if you want to prevent page navigation eg. from links, you can add `return false;` to the JavaScript:

```
    webEngine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<State>() {
          @Override
          public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends State> ov, State oldState, State newState) {
              if (newState == State.SUCCEEDED) {
                  JSObject window = (JSObject) webEngine.executeScript("window");
                  webEngine.executeScript("var nonJQuery = function (event) {\n" +
                          "    clickController.printId(this);\n" +
                          "    event.preventDefault();\n" +
                          "    event.stopPropagation();\n" +
                          "    return false;\n" +
                          "};\n" +
                          "var elements = document.querySelectorAll(\"*\");\n" +
                          "for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {\n" +
                          "    elements[i].addEventListener(\"click\", nonJQuery, false);\n" +
                          "}");
                  window.setMember("clickController", new WebController());
              }
          }
      }
    );
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I'm not using jQuery. Is it possible to do this using only javascript? How can I modify the last piece of code?

Comment: @naveenbharadwaj I've added a non-jQuery version.

Comment: u mean adding it to HTML document? I will be loading different websites in webView, not particularly one HTML document

Comment: Change coming in, one moment.

Comment: thanks a lot..I have one last query..If I click on any link, I just need to get the detail and not reload the page..Any possibility to do that? for example, I click on a link to get the ID. It returns the ID, but the page gets redirected. I dont want that to happen.

Comment: Hey - can do, but it'll break the functionality of the page obviously. Check final update.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78501/discussion-between-naveenbharadwaj-and-evan-knowles).