# How to get the messages of JavaScript console to JavaFX

Tags: java, javascript, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

In my JavaFX application, I have a `WebView` to load HTML contents. I wonder if there is a way to debug the HTML inside `WebView`, I mean get the messages of the Javascript console and retrieve it in my JavaFx application. Just in case, if an error occured in the HTML document, I will be able to see the errors.

Comment: Are you looking for this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30390257/how-to-catch-return-value-from-javascript-in-javafx/30390913#30390913

Comment: @KennethClark, that's not what Im looking for.